# undefined environment vmatrix

Tags: editors, syntax

I am an absolute beginner in LaTeX... I am trying to learn it so that I can use it to ask question in websites.
I have faced the following problem...
I have learned some syntax which is used to describe the cross product from a course in Coursera.
It is written as follows

```
$$\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i}&mathbf{j}&\mathbf{k}\\
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_a&b_2&b_3
\end{vmatrix}$$
```

and when I typed it in my Latex editor, it didn't work. However, when I posted it in Coursera it worked!!!
I wonder if the problem is due to the difference in software.
They use MathJax (I use an interpreter named MiKTeX, and an editor named TeXMaker).

I will upload an image of what happens in the editor.
Thank you.

[image: I know I have forgotten a \ before writing (mathbf), but even when I fixed this, the code still doesn't work]

Comment: vmatrix is defined in `amsmath` so add `\usepackage{amsmath}` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: also do not use `$$` in latex, use `\[...\]`    see https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10 for general math tutorial

Comment: I am very grateful to you, Mr. Carlisle.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Do note that MathJax questions are often (usually?) off-topic on this site because MathJax is technically a different thing than LaTeX, even though they share the same syntax (which is why learning one can be useful for the other).  But since your question is definitely about LaTeX and not MathJax, all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vmatrix` is defined in `amsmath` so add `\usepackage{amsmath}` before `\begin{document}`